# How to catch the exit code of a CMDEXEC SQL Server Job?

Tags: sql-server, exit-code, sql-server-agent, sql-server-job

The following SQL Server job always exits with return code 0 indicating success, when in fact it does not do its job, i.e. it does not delete "test.txt". 
How can I catch the actual exit code (something like %ERRORLEVEL%, or a 'permission denied'-like message, or any meaningful response indicating success or failure of @command at msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep)?

Remarks:

- *{DBname}* is the name of the database I am the owner of
- *{proxyName}* is the name of the SQL Server Agent Proxy (that is active to the 'Operating system (CmdExec)' subsystem) belonging to a credential that maps to a Windows domain login in SQL Server that has full control to *{folderUNC}*
- *{folderUNC}* is the full UNC path to the folder where "test.txt" is

A few details that might be useful:

- Server: Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise Edition (64-bit) version 9.00.4060.00
- OS: Microsoft Windows NT 5.2 (3790)
- I am not a sysadmin, but only the owner of database *{DBname}*

CODE:

```
USE {DBname}
GO

DECLARE @returnCode AS INT
DECLARE @jobName NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @jobStep1Name SYSNAME

SET @jobName = 'CMDEXEC Test Job' 
SET @jobStep1Name = 'CMDEXEC Test Job Step 1'

EXEC @returnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_job 
    @job_name = @jobName,
    @enabled = 1,
    @start_step_id = 1,
    @notify_level_eventlog = 2,
    @delete_level = 0;

 IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @returnCode <> 0)
     PRINT N'Error @ sp_add_job. @@ERROR = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @@ERROR) + 
          N' @returnCode = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @returnCode

EXEC @returnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = @jobName, 
    @step_id = 1, 
    @step_name = @jobStep1Name, 
    @subsystem = 'CMDEXEC', 
    @command = 'DEL {folderUNC}\test.txt',
    @cmdexec_success_code = 0,
    @on_success_action = 1,
    @on_fail_action = 2,
    @proxy_name = '{proxyName}';

 IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @returnCode <> 0)
     PRINT N'Error @ sp_add_job. @@ERROR = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @@ERROR) + 
          N' @returnCode = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @returnCode

EXEC @returnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver 
    @job_name = @jobName;

 IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @returnCode <> 0)
     PRINT N'Error @ sp_add_job. @@ERROR = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @@ERROR) + 
          N' @returnCode = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @returnCode

EXEC @returnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 
    @job_name = @jobName,
    @step_name = @jobStep1Name;

 IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @returnCode <> 0)
     PRINT N'Error @ sp_add_job. @@ERROR = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @@ERROR) + 
          N' @returnCode = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @returnCode

EXEC @returnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job 
    @job_name = @jobName;

 IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @returnCode <> 0)
     PRINT N'Error @ sp_add_job. @@ERROR = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @@ERROR) + 
          N' @returnCode = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @returnCode
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble seems to be that `del` does not set the `errorlevel` when it fails. There are several ways to 'work around' this, but personally I'd go for either writing my own delete.exe, or via a .bat file.

Example : (delete.bat)

```
@echo off

del "%1"
if exist "%1" GOTO FAIL
EXIT /B 0

:FAIL
ECHO "File still there ! (%1)"
EXIT /B 1
```

And you can call it like this (`@command`):

```
delete.bat c:\test.txt
```

it will return as failed when the file is still there after supposedly being deleted.